# Script para verificar se o CPF corresponde ao nome

Tags: php

Em um sistema, para aumentar a segurança e a confiabilidade dos dados, seria interessante saber se o CPF informado ao site corresponde ao nome fornecido. Não encontrei nenhum script na internet para fazer esse tipo de correspondência.
Como a Receita Federal, possui disponível no link https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaPublica.asp
uma página para verificar o nome e a situação da pessoa dona do CPF a partir do número deste e a data de nascimento, creio que isso pudesse ser mais tranquilo.

Comment: Não acredito que seja possível pois a mesma requer um código captcha a ser preenchido, e desconheço qualquer API pública para que terceiros possam realizar a consulta.

Comment: se isso é realmente essencial considere serviços de consulta ao crédito do serasa, spc...

Answer (score 0):

A formação de um número de CPF não leva em consideração o nome ou data de nascimento de uma pessoa, ou seja, não é possível fazer essa verificação através de cálculos ou algo do tipo.

Só seria possível se houvesse uma forma de consultar o banco de dados nacional e confrontar as informações.

O problema é que esse é um cadastro interno da Receita Federal e que ao que tudo indica, (infelizmente) não é e nem tem previsão de ser liberado para o público consultar através de uma API/WebService. Coisa que eu acho que já deveriam ter liberado algo nesse sentido à muito tempo.