# Receber dados de outra página

Tags: php, query

Fala galera, estou criando uma loja com um amigo, uma das medidas de segurança é a verificação se o CPF realmente existe. pensando nisso achamos um site: https://www.situacaocadastral.com.br/ que consulta CPF, como posso enviar o CPF do usuário para essa página e exibir o resultado na minha página?

Comment: Não tem como, pelo que percebi, o sistema deles usam api provavelmente da receita Federal, que quando a pessoa digita o cpf e aperta o botão de pesquisar, é enviado os dados para a api e este site apenas recebe os dados de retorno na tela. O que vcs teriam que fazer é uma sistema para acessar a api da receita e não esta página em si.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141182/8063